# Optimize Scroll Bar HTML

Tags: html, css, optimization, scrollbar

I want to change the color , width or height of the scroll bar in the browser when I run my web application

I have tried many methods and see many examples but it's not working like this :

[image]

Note : I tried on Google-Chrome , Firefox , microsoft-edge and IE.

Answer (score 0):

**These will work for chrome, just a sample css :**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #aaa;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Ok , it's working on Chrome , but how can i do that for firefox , IE or Safari ?